# TabBar Hide WebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

i'm writing an application , has a tab bar and there is a web view and i want to hide this web view when someone push to the same page's tab bar button item . Please Help !!!

Answer (score 0):

on your tabbarbuttonclick write:-

```
[*yourwebviewname* setHidden:YES];
```

or if you do not want to use it further can can also do

```
[*yourwebviewname* removeFromSuperView];
```

Try this:-

```
NSArray *arr =[self.view subviews];
    for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++){
        UIView *vw=[arr objectAtIndex:i];
        if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]])
            [vw removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

Comment: rhx for answer :)  i'm asking that how to hide the webView when i touch to tab bar item .. i want to reach to view by tabBar item

Comment: if u want that web view for some other reason for that you can try my edited answer